# In there a convenient way to have multiline input in libedit/editline

Tags: c, command-line, readline, editline

Using libedit/[editline](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/), and trying to figure out a good way to do multiline input/editing. The target is an SQL client, where queries will often span multiple lines and terminate with `;`.

I can call `el_gets`, and process each line of input, stopping when I see the terminating `;`. I can even concatenate those and store them as a single entry in el_history - and it will correctly access them when using the arrows to scroll through history.

However, when entering the command and after starting a new line, I can no longer use the arrows to move up and edit the previous line. E.g.:

```
prompt> SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
```

At that point, I'd like to be able to use the up-arrow, to move up and edit the text already entered on the first line. Is this possible? How would one do so? I assume that using `el_gets` isn't correct in this case, since it would remove the line from the editline buffering, yet I don't see an alternative API that would work.

Thoughts?

Comment: did you look at the source code for http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqsh/ . I'm certain sqsh allowed for multi-line edits. Pretty sure about readline integration. Good luck.

Comment: I'll take a look at that! thanks.